# unset() in multidimensional array check if key exists first

Tags: php

My array:

```
$array = array(
  'test' => 'hello',
  'something' => array(
    'sub1' => 'foo'
  )
);
```

I'd like to use:

```
if(array_key_exists('sub1', $array['something'])
{
  unset($array['something']['sub1'];
}
```

The `unset` part works, but the if statement returns false while the `sub1` item is definitely there. Why is this?

Comment: Your code doesn't even execute, there at least 4 Parse Errors...

Comment: Without all the syntax errors the code works fine https://3v4l.org/4FnHp voting typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reformat your code a little. However, here is the formatted code,

```
 $arr = [
    'test' => 'hello',
    'something' => [
        'sub1' => 'foo'
     ]
  ];

  if(
     is_array($arr['something']) && 
     array_key_exists('sub1', $arr['something'])
   )
   {
      unset($arr['something']['sub1']);
   }

  print_r($arr);
```

and I am getting following result,

```
Array
(
    [test] => hello
    [something] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Can you elaborate on what is it that you want to do ??